# matplotlib imshow wrong coloring bug

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the below code. It is creating an image of a matrix of labels through a custom colormap, with a very large number of different colors due to the many labels. For some reason this is creating nonsense plots, see the image below. In the window itself it also looks like nonsense, but then looks fine when I enlarge the window. Very strange. What is going on here? How can I work around this?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from scipy import ndimage

p = .4
N = 512
rng = np.random.default_rng(2036-8-12)
lb = rng.uniform(size=(N, N)) < p
lbl, nl = ndimage.label(lb)
print(f'{nl} unique clusters of bonds')
colors = plt.get_cmap('hsv')(np.linspace(0, 1, nl))
rng.shuffle(colors)
colors = np.vstack((mcolors.to_rgba('black'), colors))
cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(colors)
plt.imshow(lbl, cmap=cmap)
plt.savefig('perc_1.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=400)
plt.show()
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygSpN.jpg) nonsense is what it writes to png. Individual pixels here contain many different colors. Inexplicable, seems like a bug. (Unfortunately it converted it to jpg so it's less clear.) [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azpbo.png) is what it looks like when I zoom in, then it's the expected behavior. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSQZn.png) is a clear comparison.

Comment: Could be an issue with the interpolation. Try adding `interpolation = 'none'` to your imshow.